# How do i update an existing database to support ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web solution that I upgraded to ASP.NET Identity 2.0. The problem i now face it that i have some solutions of this software running in production at several customers. When I try installing the new software (with ASP.NET Identity 2.0) on the existing database (full of their data). I then get an error: "The model backing the "ApplicationDbContext" context has changed singe the database was created"

How do i update the database in the existing solution to a database that fits the new ASP.NET Identity? I looked at the ASPnetUsers table and there has been added several new columns.

Is there a way to disable this check? Or is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would create a new project/database containing just the ASP.Net Identity 2.0 features and create a dummy user (just to make sure that it all works correctly).

Then, use [schema comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) between the new database and your existing database. You can then generate scripts to create the user tables in your customers' database.

You may still have further integration work to do, but it should get you over the hump.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't use EF code first. You could run your project in dev using code first and get the full DB structure including the Identity tables, then compare against the prod schema and implement the differences.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the hint:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx